# Finding Lookup item numerical values in MS Dynamics

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have a site powered by ExpressionEngine 2.5.x, using Freeform, integrated to post form data to MS Dynamics CRM 2011. The extension is nicely scalable, I can change the mapping, all that excellent stuff. My problem is how to find mapping values for Lookup fields in MS Dynamics.

I am trying to map form fields from the site forms, into MS Dynamics. Some of the fields are Lookups, in MS Dynamics. Our mapping calls out the numerical value of the Lookup item, rather than its name. (Which is good, because ppl can change the text names in the MS Dynamics console without breaking the mapping.)

My question is: I know how to find the actual back-end field names of form fields within MS Dynamics. But how to I find the numerical values of the picklist items and lookup fields? Say I have a Lookup field, for Lead Source (called campaignid). The items are:

- web
- online
- radio ad
- flyer
- word of mouth
- other

I know that when I edit options in an option set, I can see their numerical value. Where can I edit options in a lookup field? I've tried looking under *Settings > Customizations > Customize the System*, but didn't see anything called *lookup*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lookups are pointers to entities. They do not have numerical values like regular option sets. So I guess that you will have entity called Campaign (or lead) so you can check which campaigns exist in the crm DB where each entity will have view in the DB.

Answer (score 2):

Let's see if i understand your question. You don't have a Lookup option like Option Set because a lookup is consequence of a relationship 1:N between two entities. So for edit a lookup you need edit a record of a entity. In lookup fields you don't have numerical values, you have guid that represent individually a record, so in a record a lookup is stored in database as a guid. Check this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D7qZlINs-2g).

Check [here](http://crmbusiness.wordpress.com/2011/02/21/crm-2011-quick-way-to-find-a-guid-using-a-crm-form/) how find this guid with the record open.

Comment: So essentially I was looking for something that doesn't exist, because that's not how those fields work? Okay - that at least lets me know that I wasn't going totally insane. Based on your and Gregs' answers, I think I'll have to set these field values with process rules, based on the content of other fields that the forms send back. Thank you to you both.

Answer (score 1):

A look-up field is, roughly speaking a pointer to en entity (in C# it's referred to as *EntityReference* instead of *Entity*) and it consist mainly of a guid and logical name of *something*.

Usually, in the code, when you have an entity, in order to access the fields of its lookup-connected entity, you'll need to make an extra query for that.

So, if you have a *Contact* instance and need to see the address of its parent customer, you'll have to get the guid and logical name (in this case it'll be *Account*) and retrieve the data for it separately.

EDIT:

Suppose that you have created an instance of *Contact* entity and you'd like to access its *lastName* field. Then you can simply refer to it as follows.

```
var value = Xrm.Page.getAttribute(“lastName”).getValue();
```

On the same form, there's also a field that refers to an *Account* instance (its name is *parentCustomerId*. Suppose now that you'd like to get the *fullName* field of the *Account*. One could expect the following to work.

```
var account = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("parentCusomterId").getValue();
var name = account.getAttribute("fullName").getValue();
```

However, that's not going to work, because the *parentCutomerId* is a look-up field. It means that it only contains a guid (a pointer, a reference) identifying an other entity. You'll have to use it (the guid) in order to fetch the instance that the look-up is "mentioning". **Then** you'll be able to check it's properties.

Comment: ...I have no idea what you just said. This is my first time using any CRM, and I'm doing integration! Yeah, this is a bit of a challenge. I also have no formal programming background (I can do some **real** basic JavaScript if I have lots of time and cheat sheets), so I'm probably going to have to digest your first sentence quite a bit more before I can grok it. I think that this will be very good information for me to have, but right now it's not coming through. Sorry! (But thank you for adding information.)

Comment: See my edit. Sorry if I overshoot. And yes, given your information it's going to be a challenge. But I'm sure you'll make it. After all, you've got Stack Overflow.   :)